# my default value not working. showing invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    dob: Date,
    address: {
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        country: String,
        postalcode: Number,
    },
profile: String,
role: {   
    Type: String,
    enum: ['user','vendor'],
    default: 'user'
},
socialMedia: {
    facebook: String,
    instagram: String,
    twitter: String,
},

},{
    timestamps: true,
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema)
module.exports = UserModel;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdVYn.png)
```

i don't why when i put my default value it shows the error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbV8T.png)

1. when i don't put default value the code runs without any error but after the default value the error starts showing .

Comment: `Type: String,`should be `type: String,` in role field, can you update and try?

Comment: ```Type: String,```should be ```type: String,``` it should work.